# Checkmarx: Spring Overly Permissive Cross Origin Resource Sharing Policy in Java

Tags: java, spring, security, checkmarx

My project was scanned by Checkmarx, and all the controller methods had this low level risk: **Spring Overly Permissive Cross Origin Resource Sharing Policy**.

```
public JSONObject example(@RequestBody JSONObject param) {...}
```

The report doesn't say anything about the problem. Neither why it cause the risk, nor how to fix it.

We have CORS setting in the application.yaml:

```
security:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: 
      https://example1.com,
      https://example2.com
    allowed-methods:
      GET,
      POST,
      PUT
```

But still showing this vulnerability. Is there anyway to prevent Checkmarx showing this?

Comment: Disable the check? I suspect it scans for `@CrossOrigin` but there are other means to do that as well which aren't taken into account ( I suspect). Those rule based static checks will only get you so far.

Comment: @M.Deinum Our client were unwilling to do that, but maybe it's the only way to resolve this problem... Thank you for your reply!